# I cant connect the SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, connect

All I get is this error.

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to .local.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The network path was not found

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I have tried some of the answers I saw on other threads for example go on sql server config and then right click tcp/ip and click on IP addresses but the IP addresses bit doesn't work why is that along withe the other solution?

A long time a go I had the same problem and found a solution by doing something in control panel but I lost the solution and cant remember it. :-(

Comment: Hi @Esdras, did my solution fix your issue? I can provide more information if needed. If it resolves your problem, could you accept my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Sadly no! I might just download a different version of sql to see if it works. i am currently using sql 2012

Comment: Installing a new version of SQL Server might not be able fix your problem. Did you look at your _SQL Server Configuration Manager_ and is the SQL Server running?

Comment: Yes I have checked SQL Server Configuration Manager, although i'm not quite sure what I am supposed to be looking for and how to check is server is running. But everything is enabled including TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Server instance is running on local host? Here're some of valid names that you can try in order to connect to the local instance via SQL Server Management Studio:

- `.`
- `(local)`
- `localhost`

**Or even better**, while opening the SSMS, you can droll down the list from *`Server name: <Browse for more...>`* and find all the local servers running and choose the one you wished to connect.

If there's not any instance available, then your local SQL Server is probably stopped. In this case, run the program *SQL Server Configuration Manager* and verify whether your instances are running.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, You need to put Servername as *localhost* or . if you have local instance to connect to.

I think you are putting *.local* as the servername. It is throwing error.